# Java - weird static String behavior - new String("xxx") vs "xxx"

Tags: java, string, static, initialization

```
public class Test {

    private static final String str1 = new String("en");
    private static Test instance = initInstance();

    private static final String str2 = new String("en");
    private static final String str3 = "en";

    private Test() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    private static Test initInstance() {
        instance = new Test();
        System.out.println(str1 + ',' + str2 + ',' + str3);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**Theoretically** with statics everywhere it should result in "en,en,en".

Result: "en,null,en"

Expected: "en,null,null" (since i discovered statics order actually matters)

Could somebody explain this?
What is so different about "en" and new String("en")?

Comment: +1 because I had _no idea_ you could initialize inline like that...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. At the time you invoke the method, str2 is not yet initialized (fields are initialized in order of declaration) and str3 is a compile-time constant.

Compile-time constants are inlined by the compiler in the class file. new String("..") is not a constant, because it uses a constructor.

String constants are defined by the string literal: "", and they are placed in a string pool in the jvm instance so that they are reused. Contrary to that, using new String(..) creates a new instance, and so should be avoided.

Comment: Should `inlined` be changed to `interned`?

Answer (score 11):

This happens because class variables initialized with *constants* are initialized first, and only then are more complex initializers (like your expressions using `new String()`) done (those are then done in source order). See [JLS §8.3.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.1):

> 8.3.2.1. Initializers for Class Variables
>
> *[...]*
>
> At run-time, `static` fields that are `final` and that are initialized with constant expressions ([§15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) are initialized first ([§12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)). This also applies to such fields in interfaces ([§9.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3.1)). These fields are "constants" that will never be observed to have their default initial values ([§4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)), even by devious programs ([§13.4.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9)).

Answer (score 4):

**1.** Its because `str3 = "en" is a String literal in literal pool, and str1 = new String("en") is a String object` at the String object pool.

**2.** As **"en" is a literal, ie "constant" it will be initialized at the beginning**.

**3.** Its also called as **Constant Folding**, pre calculation of the constants to execute faster.